# Can I query Records with Status of Soft Bounce?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, journeybuilder, send-email

Is there a way for me to query records that has a status of 'Soft Bounce' for an email that was sent using journey builder and store those records in a data extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a query to select all unsubscribed subscribers from the master subscribers table with an EXISTS ON clause using the Data Extension that the journey is using:

```
SELECT
S.SubscriberKey,
S.EmailAddress,
S.Status, 
FROM _Subscribers S 
WHERE S.Status = 'bounced'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Journey_DE] WHERE Email_Address = S.EmailAddress)
```

You might be able to tweak this to what you need? You'll also need to set a data extension up to put them in.